# Eclipse debug configuration does not load two versions of the same plugin

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

My Eclipse RCP application currently uses 2 versions of the same plugin (`javax.servlet 2.5.0` and `javax.servlet 3.1.0`).
When I debug the application from my Eclipse (Mars 4.5.2) workspace I see that the lowest version of the `javax.servlet` is not loaded nor appears as to be available as you can see in the following console snippet (note that `javax.servlet` `2.5.0` does not even appear. `javax.servlet.jsp` is a different plugin).

```
osgi> ss javax.servlet

Framework is launched.

id  State       Bundle
41  INSTALLED   javax.servlet.jsp_2.0.0.v200806031607
8947    ACTIVE      javax.servlet_3.1.0.201605180802
```

I've taken a look to my debug configuration and both versions (`2.5.0` and `3.1.0`) are selected to be used during debug sessions.
[image: Debug configuration]

However, when I install my application and execute it without using the Eclipse environment, the OSGI framework is able to load both bundles without problems as described in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21589333/equinox-osgi-activating-two-versions-of-the-same-bundle).

What I am missing? How can I debug my application from Eclipse by loading both plugins?

Answer (score 0):

OSGi has lazy loading. Having those in Debug configuration make the INSTALLED, then OSGi will activate them only when necessary.

It seems like in the case of your Debug configuration, using only the older version is sifficient whereas in the target environment, sometginh requires 3.1.0 to be activated too.

Your Debug configuration and target environment are not equivalent there.

To know what requires it, you can start your target environment with the `-console` flag and use usual commands to diagnostic dependencies. For example, trying the uninstall command on 3.1.0 should give you an explanation of what depends on it before completing.

Comment: Thanks for your contribution but I think my question was not clear enough (I've edited it). The `javax.servlet` `2.5.0`does not even appear in the Eclipse's OSGI console. This means that Eclipse does not even try to install the plugin (`javax.servlet.jsp`is not the plugin I'm referring to).